# github non fast-forward error

Tags: git, github

I know this has been asked a bunch of times, but my problem seems slightly different

```
To https://github.com/sr/foo.git
08a86ab..3d1ece2  master -> master
! [rejected]        y_dev -> y_dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/sr/foo.git'
```

ok, so I need to do a pull from y_dev, which I tried:

```
git pull origin y_dev
From https://github.com/sr/foo
* branch            y_dev  -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

This perplexes me. I thought a pull should fix this for me, but there is something I am not understanding. An explanation/fix appreciated

Comment: To help debug, you can run git log on both branches to see if there is actually any difference between the branches. So `git log y_dev` and `git log remotes/origin/y_dev`

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch of changes introduced in y_dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pulling branch `y_dev` into your current checked-out branch, which is most likely `master`. Thus you are not actually bringing the local `y_dev` up to date with your `git-pull`.

Try:

```
git checkout y_dev
git pull origin y_dev
git push origin y_dev
```

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same realization. Unfortunately, I was unable to checkout y_dev because of local changes, so I had to stash them first.Another realization I had was 'git push' was not the same as 'git push origin master', the latter was what I needed

Comment: Another pro-tip, you can push a local branch to a remote with a different name with `git push origin y_dev:master` and you can squash upstream branches with `git push origin +y_dev:master`. Be careful with the latter.