# Fixing after push non-fast-forward branch

Tags: git

I know that there are many question linked to "non-fast-forward branch push". I have seen them an I have found an answer that I thought it was the best, because I did not want a force push ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692748/3062311))

My problem is that before merging I had:

```
* afd733f (HEAD, feat/fix_branch) comment32154
* 424ab31 comment6543
| * d73a555 (origin/feat/fix_branch) comment6543
|/    
* d7f3fad (origin/branch, branch) comment6541
```

Now, how did I get something like this? I do not know...

But I have done the steps in the [answer mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692748/3062311) and now it is like this:

```
* 4cd3543 (HEAD, origin/feat/fix_branch, feat/fix_branch) Merge branch 'feat/fix_branch'
|\
| * d73a555 (origin/feat/fix_branch) comment6543
* |  afd733f (HEAD, feat/fix_branch) comment32154
* | 424ab31 comment6543
|/    
* d7f3fad (origin/branch, branch) comment6541
```

I just wanted to fix that without having a kind of loop. I just wanted one line. Is it possible to go back and have something like:

```
* 4cd3543 (HEAD, origin/feat/fix_branch, feat/fix_branch) Merge branch 'feat/fix_branch'
|
* afd733f comment32154
* 424ab31 comment6543
|    
* d7f3fad (origin/branch, branch) comment6541
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if that was your local copy, but you've *pushed* your branch back to origin since making the change. That complicates things.

If, when you first got your loop, you'd noticed it and just done

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^ # discard the merge commit you don't like
$ git rebase origin/feat/fix_branch
```

you'd have the result you want.

Now, you can still do that, but you'll have to force push it back to origin, which is a problem if anyone else pulled your merge commit.

Note that the question you linked doesn't address this at all - it describes how to avoid causing the problem in the first place, where the OP was on the wrong branch.

---

In general, I wouldn't bother fixing this "loop" - there's nothing that terrifying about seeing a merge commit in the history.

However, if you want to avoid it in future, just use `git pull --rebase`. You can even configure this as the default.

Comment: I cannot test your answer, because I have done a force push and now it seems to be as I wanted. If I do a rebase what is happening?